# iOS: Swift: SDWebImage: cell.customImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageURL) crashes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sdwebimage

I'm using CocoaPods with SDWebImage (3.8.2) with a new Swift 3 project (XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)) and the following code compiles fine within a UICollectionViewController:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      ...
      cell.customImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, completed:{
        (SDWebImageCompletionBlock) in

      })
      ...
    }
```

I've imported SDWebImage at the top of the swift file. customImageView is a UIImageView defined within a custom UICollectionViewCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!
```

however this crashes on run with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:completed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...'
```

Any ideas why this is compiling fine but crashing at runtime?

Comment: The lastest version is v-4.0.2.beta,use the newest version .

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(inherited)` to your 'Other Linker Flags' in the build settings

Answer (score 0):

Check the outlet, disconnect and reconnect the outlet of your imageView